# Apache Pig extract certain lines in a relation

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm using Apache Pig to do some data analysis work. I have a relation A that contains 100,000 records. And I would like to split them evenly into 100 files, each containing 1000 records. Can I do this without UDF?

Comment: 100,000 lines isn't very many, and 100 files each containing 1000 records wouldn't be ideal either - are you sure you need to do this within the context of Hadoop? It would be pretty easy to solve with a non-distributed Java/Python job.

Comment: well, of course that is true, but I just eliminated a complex context and just wrote the core problem. Maybe I should consider another way to finish that.